# Why does not go to the product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Brought the goods, when you click on the product, does not go into the card of this product, the link is formed correctly, but the content of the page does not change, that's how I brought the product:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content-about">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap-product">
      <h2 class="about-title">Мои товары</h2>
      <div class="product-list">
        <?php 
          $custom_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product'));
          if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
          global $product;      
        ?>
        <div class="item-product">
          <div class="img-prod">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="name-prod"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
          <div class="rating-prod"></div>
          <div class="price-prod"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></div>
          <div class="add-cart">
            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
         <?php /*woocommerce_content();*/ ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When you click on the name of the product does not go to this product:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7phJ.png)

Comment: i cant understand your problem but i'm pretty sure its in `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart` part

Comment: guessing that this is your archive file for the products right - not your single-product.php

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you misunderstood me.

My problem is that when you click on the product name, it does not go to this product, but remains on this page, although the url changes to:
my-site/product/смартфон-blackview-s8-золото/